Limiting max accelerations in ease curve
I'm writing some code to calculate positions for a robotic joint when given a goto command. I want to use a ease in/out curve to ramp up and down during the move. The curve function I'm using is a cubic curve but I'd ideally like to support any curve function.
function easeInOutCubic(t) {
  return t < 0.5 ? 4 * t ** 3 : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * t + 2, 3) / 2
}

function easeLinear(t) {
  return t
}

With this I have a parameter limiting the max acceleration value as that's important with robotics. My code works with the easeLinear function, but when using the cubic curve, it causes the acceleration to spike over the max acceleration by 2-3x.
I understand this is because constraining the curve to the same time as the linear function would mathematically have to have a faster acceleration in some spots and to compensate I need to increase the time that the curve function has compared to the linear function.

In this image I show that running the cubic ease and linear ease for the same duration, it would result in the red spot to over accelerate. I need to stretch the time out to constrain the entire curve to be under the linear line to have it stay within my acceleration limits.
I am unsure how to calculate this this time scale factor though. How could I go about doing this?
Here is a jsfiddle with my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jrj2211/m9obp27h/


How come you write "t**3" and math.pow(..., 3)?

Thats just the standard function libraries use for cubic easing. See https://easings.net/#easeInOutCubic at the bottom of the page uses this formula which is where I got it from.

Some of these "standard function libraries" are so massively inefficient that it is breath-taking. It may be that modern optimizers will spot that integer $3$ in the math.pow function, say "screw this for a lark" and replace it with the obvious two multiplications. But I can never bring myself to trust them to that extent. I do trust them to do the same translation for "**3", as that was one of the very first optimizations ever programmed.

In mathematical notation, your $_\wedge^\text{velocity}$ curve is (noting that $1 - (-2t+2)^3/2 = 1 - 4(1-t)^3$):
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}0,&t < 0\\4t^3,&0\le t < \frac12\\1 - 4(1-t)^3,&\frac12 \le t < 1\\1,& 1\le t\end{cases}$$
where I've extended it outside $[0,1]$ it indicate the values should be stationary at least up to acceleration.
The velocity$_\wedge^\text{acceleration}$ is the time derivative of the function:
$$\dot f(t) = \begin{cases}0,&t < 0\\12t^2,&0\le t < \frac12\\12(1-t)^2,&\frac12 \le t < 1\\0,& 1\le t\end{cases}$$
And the acceleration$_\wedge^\text{jerk}$ is the second time derivative:
$$\ddot f(t) = \begin{cases}0,&t < 0\\24t,&0\le t < \frac12\\-24(1-t) = 24t-24,&\frac12 < t < 1\\0,& 1\le t\end{cases}$$
The acceleration$_\wedge^\text{jerk}$ rises linearly from $0$ to $12$ at $t = \frac 12$. Then it instantaneously drops to $-12$ and rises linearly again back up to $0$. [The remainder is more substantially edited:] That sudden change in jerk is no more physically possible than similar changes in velocity or acceleration, and will be ameliorated into something smooth by the actual physics. However at the fourth derivative of position, the spike in forces caused by the sudden commanded change should be within acceptable levels.
The acceleration raises from $0$ at time $0$ to $3$ at time $\frac 12$. Then it decreases back to $0$ at time $1$. So the maximum acceleration is $3$.
But this function is just a generic template that must be scaled to fit actual uses. Translation to start at $(0,0)$ does not affect acceleration, so we can still assume that. But the values of $f$ will in general need to rise by some amount $V$ meters/second instead of $1$ meter/second, and take $T$ seconds to do it, not just $1$ second. Thus the velocity formula is $v = Vf\left(\frac tT\right)$, with acceleration $\dot v = \frac VT\dot f\left(\frac tT\right)$, with maximum acceleration $\frac{3V}T$
So if you want to keep this below some maximum acceleration $A_\text{max}$, it means
$$\frac{3V}T \le A_\text{max}\\
T \ge\frac{3V}{A_\text{max}}$$

I failed to mention that my curve describes my velocity over time, which I believe you used the assumption of it describing position. With that, I believe thats effectively what you were describing of pushing the discontinuity to the next higher derivative. If I plot the accelerations with the curve used as velocity, then the acceleration does not instantaneously go negative, whereas using a linear velocity function it does. I've updated the JS fiddle link to plot the position, velocity and acceleration of my current implementation.

Of course, if the original function is velocity instead of position, my comments about acceleration would not apply, being instead true about the time-derivative of acceleration. I have changed the post to discuss the behavior of the first derivative instead of the second, with the requisite change in the inequality satisfied by time.
